# Docker Container Data Volume mapping failed?

Tags: linux, database, docker, cloud, daemon

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see in first figure, the container ran just fine. But when I created a test file in container's volume, and then when I checked the corresponding mapping directory in my host machine, I found an empty folder. Please tell me what I did wrong and what the solution is. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: How did you create a test file in the container volume? Please update question with steps.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the `mount` option (available as of 17.06)? It tends to be more verbose.

Something like `--mount type=bind,source=/data/mysql/data,target=/var/lib/data`

Read more here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/